# node-rest-client POST Vs. PUT

Tags: node.js, express, npm

Has anyone used [node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client)? For POST and PUT methods, it says "To send data to remote site using POST or PUT methods, just add a data attribute to args object:" So how can I distinguish between a POST call and PUT call?

Comment: Are you talking about on the remote server side or for the client? Because the documentation you linked clearly states how to make a `post` call?

Comment: Yes it is clear for POST, but how about a PUT call? If the url is the same just the method is different, how can I distinguish between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a `put` request, you just use the `put` method instead of the `post` or `get` methods.

```
client.put("http://remote.site/rest/xml/method", function(data, response){
        // parsed response body as js object
        console.log(data);
        // raw response
        console.log(response);
    });
```